# Pandas: get the row which has column value and update comments column with another value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the below dataframe

```
       FQDN       ip address     verstatus        Comments
0     pp.xx.com   XX.XXX.XXX.XX   Developed           NaN
1     qq.xx.com   XX.XXX.XXX.XX   NaN                NaN
2     gg.xx.com   XX.XXX.XXX.XX   Reserve            NaN
3     gg.xx.com   XX.XXX.XXX.XX   Testing            NaN
```

so I need to update then comments when the verstatus not equal "Developed" or "NaN"(else anything)

so expected result would be

```
       FQDN       ip address     version status        Comments
0     pp.xx.com   XX.XXX.XXX.XX   Developed           NaN
1     qq.xx.com   XX.XXX.XXX.XX   NaN                NaN
2     gg.xx.com   XX.XXX.XXX.XX   Reserve            Reserve Status
3     gg.xx.com   XX.XXX.XXX.XX   Testing            Testing Status
```

I tried

```
df['Comments'] = df.apply(lambda x: x["version status"]+" Status" if x['version status'] != 'Developed' or x['version status'].notna()  else x['Comments'], axis=1)
```

But it not works properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.notna()` is a pandas function, but `x['version status']` is a string, you should use `pd.isna` like this:

```
df['Comments'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Comments'] if x['version status']=='Developed' 
                                                     or pd.isna(x['version status']) 
                                                  else x["version status"]+" Status", 
                          axis=1)
```

I think this would be cleaner:

```
# version status is either Developed or nan
cond = df['verstatus'].eq('Developed') | df['verstatus'].isna()

# you can update with `np.where`
df['Comments'] = np.where(cond, df['Comments'], df['verstatus'] + ' Status')
```

Comment: what is np?? here  also `np.where(cond, df['Comments', df['verstatus'] + ' Status')`  bracket not closed

Comment: Updated, `np` is standard for `numpy`, just like `pd` is short for `pandas`: `import numpy as np; import pandas as pd`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use:

```
cond = ~df['verstatus'].isin(['Developed', np.nan])
df['Comments'] = df['Comments'].mask(cond, df['verstatus'] + ' Status')
```

`OUTPUT`

```
        FQDN     ip address  verstatus        Comments
0  pp.xx.com  XX.XXX.XXX.XX  Developed             NaN
1  qq.xx.com  XX.XXX.XXX.XX        NaN             NaN
2  gg.xx.com  XX.XXX.XXX.XX    Reserve  Reserve Status
3  gg.xx.com  XX.XXX.XXX.XX    Testing  Testing Status
```

Comment: Perfect working Thanks